# Long run time for older code that ran fast in older versions

Tags: version-9, machine-precision

The following code block is in Trott's [Guidebook for Programming](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/index.shtml).  The associated notebook says that this and a few other routines ran in a matter of seconds.  I killed it after half an hour.
 I am curious to know what might be the issue.  My guess is that `$MaxMachineNumber` is much bigger on my new laptop.

```
Module[{cp, cls, L = 0.02},
  (* an initial contour plot *)
  cp = ContourPlot[Im[Exp[1/(x + I y)]], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
                   PlotPoints -> 400, DisplayFunction -> Identity] /.
  (* replace large high-precision numbers by biiig machine numbers *)
     z_?(Abs[#] > $MaxMachineNumber&) :> Sign[z] $MaxMachineNumber/2;
  (* homogeneously distributed contour lines *)                 
  cls = #[[100]]& /@ Partition[Sort[Flatten[cp[[1]]]], 800];   
  (* the final contour plot *)     
  ListContourPlot[cp[[1]], MeshRange -> {{-L, L}, {-L, L}},
                  Contours -> cls, ContourLines -> False,
                  ColorFunction -> (Hue[Random[]]&), 
                  AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> None]]
```

Comment: Perhaps `ContourPlot` has changed.  in V9.0.1, `cp[[1]]` is a `GraphicsComplex`, and `MeshRange` is no longer a valid option.  I don't see how the code could work as it is.  The initial `ContourPlot` takes forever with `PlotPoints -> 400`.  It takes 10 sec. with `PlotPoints -> 25` and several GB of ram.

Comment: It's a pity - these are really impressive books, but it's difficult (particularly for us newcomers who don't remember Mathematica 7 or earlier) to get the code to run. I got the initial plot by reducing PlotPoints, but the code for the final plot is harder to adapt. (The notebooks were originally developed "in the 1991–1992 academic year on an Apple Macintosh IIfx with 20 MB RAM"... - but he must have updated them to run on a computer from the future...).

Comment: @cormullion I have all Trott books. I do not actually run any code, I just use them to read the code from the pages and try to figure what it does, but it is too advanced for me. 90% of the time I can't understand the code, but I like to look at it still because it looks amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this very case there is a very simple approach to make the code run. Between Mathematica version 5 and version 6 there were some major changes and one of them was how graphics is handled. To make it easier to run version 5 (or earlier) code with version 6 it brought the possibility to load the older/legacy (version 5) graphics handling -- and that is still possible. On my Mathematica 9 on a Windows 7 laptop the given code works without any changes when before executing I evaluate:

```
 << Version5`Graphics`
```

Note that the `MeshRange` option still is marked as invalid (red) but I think will be treated correctly by the now active version 5 graphics routines. Concerning the improvement in hardware the runtime is relatively slow (probably a minute or so) but certainly not half an hour. Memory usage doesn't look problematic as well. You should also be aware that this will switch to the older (post script based) graphics for all the following code. To switch back either restart the Kernel or do a

```
<< Version6`Graphics`
```

It most probably doesn't solve all the issues that todays Mathematica versions might have with Michael's code from the early ninties, but it certainly is something that's worth knowing when exploring his books...

Comment: Awesome.  I'd forgotten about the legacy packages.  It takes less than 3 seconds on my new-ish laptop.

Answer (score 5):

A similar, but not identical, result using more up-to-date graphics might look like this:

```
Module[{data, cls, cf, L = 0.02},
 data = Clip[With[{r = Range[-L, L, 2 L/799]}, Im[Exp[1/Outer[Plus, -I r, r]]]], 
    {-$MaxMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}];
 cls = Sort[Flatten[data]][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2000]];
 cf = With[{c = {#, Random[] // Hue} & /@ cls}, Blend[c, #] &];
 ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]
```

[image]

It's worth noting that the `ContourPlot` in the version 5 code is being used just to get an array of z values. In my code I just compute the data array directly. I've used `Span` instead of `Partition` and `Part` to extract the list of contour levels. Instead of `ListContourPlot` I have used `Blend` to construct a color function and `ArrayPlot` for display.

Comment: +1 can you do the rest of the books as well :)

Comment: Your code runs quite fast and produces a very similar result.  I appreciate the rewrite.  Very skilled.